# Should natural frequency be modeled using molecules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science, frequency, resonance, molecules

Consider an object. This can be anything from a metal ball to a table, etc. Now this object has a [natural frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_frequency). When we hit the object, it will start vibrating with a certain frequency $f$. Because of damping the amplitude of this oscillation will decrease with time. I would like to make a general model for such objects.

When we zoom in on the naturally oscillating object, the object consists of a lot of molecules. Every molecule will also be moving through space in an oscillating way. This means that every molecule also has its own frequency. All the molecules are interacting with each other.

Is it useful to model every molecule as a harmonic oscillator and all neighbouring oscillators are interacting with each other? Also, it is probably easier to assume a periodic lattice of molecules. However, many objects are not periodic lattices.

Comment: Molecules are described by quantum mechanical theories, whereas you are talking of classical mechanics.

Comment: It is _not_ true that all objects have natural frequencies. I was trying to write a long comment listing out all the different ways an object might behave when you strike it, but it got too complicated. So I'll just leave it at - no - most objects do not have a natural frequency. The universe isn't that simple. Not even molecules are that simple.

Comment: @AXensen Can we give a trivial example? How about a system with an r^4 potential? The period of such a non-linear oscillator should be explicitly amplitude dependent, should it not? The oscillation frequency should go towards zero for vanishing amplitudes if my intuition is still worth a dime. This may be similar for every "flat trough" potential. And for large amplitudes such systems should behave similar to a ball bouncing in a box. The more momentum the system has, the faster the bounces, i.e. the higher the "oscillation" frequency.

Comment: @FlatterMann That's a decent example. But I think a system that can be modelled with a 1-D potential is way too generous. Actually in that case most natural trapped systems _do_ have a natural frequency, because without fine-tuning there will be an $r^2$ term in the potential. I was rather thinking about systems that are overdamped, so not even one oscillation is observed. Or perhaps a string under tension, which has an infinite number of oscillation frequencies, all multiples of the fundamental frequency - but it oscillates at all those frequencies not just one.

Comment: @AXensen Fair enough. One has to suppress leading orders to get to my example. If we want to simplify this even further... the free particle certainly doesn't have a characteristic frequency in classical mechanics. Or is its characteristic frequency zero?

Comment: Please let me know why you downvoted the question, then I can edit it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, when we talk about molecules in a solid vibrating, we mean that the vibrating molecule is moving back and forth with respect to the lattice/its surrounding molecules. The amplitude of this oscillation is of the order of the lattice constant or less.

When you hit a macroscopic object like a ball or table, the resulting vibrations are also of a macroscopic nature, a scale much larger than single molecules. If you zoomed in to the level of a molecule, the motion would look nothing like a vibrating molecule. Instead, you'd see all neighboring molecules moving together back and forth over a much larger amplitude. The single molecule is not really vibrating, because in effect the whole lattice in its neighborhood is moving.

For this reason, it doesn't make sense to describe this phenomenon on such a microscopic level. You can and should just describe it using classical continuum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! I rephrased my question so that it doesn’t mention ‘molecules’ anymore. It is now about the  ‘particles’ from continuum mechanics.

Comment: @Riemann that's a more interesting question now, by which I mean to say, I don't know how to answer it. Hope someone else can help

Comment: Here is the new question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/799909/is-natural-frequency-a-local-or-global-property